# Jquery date validation for invalid date entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm implementing jQuery date picker. which can pick date from calendar as well as keyboard entry. When it is picked from the calendar it's working fine.

```
<input type="text" id="date" />

<script>
  $('#date').datepicker ({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
  }).on("change", function(){
    alert("You Entered: "+($(this).datepicker('getdate')));
  })
```

Problem is when I enter, lets say 02/31/2014. which is invalid. I wanted to set a custom message to the user that $ is invalid.

But Jquery is passing on today's date for wrong entries. How can I get exact value of user entry (02/31/2014)?

Comment: sidenote : You're missing the quotes (`""`) around `dateFormat`'s value

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26579899/238753) for a way to detect invalid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the getdate method of jQuery, Its automatically setting to today's date for an invalid date (not sure why it is lke this in Jquery).

```
alert("You Entered: "+($(this).datepicker('getdate')));
```

instead of this use this

```
alert("You Entered: "+($("#date").val());
```

Update: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPHhj/1/)