# jQuery UI Datepicker getDate returns today's date on invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When using jQuery UI's date-picker, if you call `getDate` while the text in the text box is not a valid date, `getDate` returns today's date.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jc6n1g3y/)

How can I distinguish between today's date and an invalid date when retrieving the date?

Comment: Over 5 years later, this defect still exists, and conflicts with the documentation "Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected." https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/datepicker/#method-getDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is normal behaviour for the widget. Here's a function that includes support for invalid date checking:

```
/* Gets the current value
 * @return Date The result or null if no date is present
 * @throws If the entered value is invalid
 */
function getDate(datePicker) {
    datePicker = $(datePicker);

    var format = datePicker.datepicker("option", "dateFormat"),
        text = datePicker.val(),
        settings = datePicker.datepicker("option", "settings");

    return $.datepicker.parseDate(format, text, settings);
}
```